# Order summary show and payment summary hide in paypal adaptive payment

Tags: php, html, paypal

I have tried this code but this is not working for me, I need both of this express checkout and adaptive payment,

I have tried different methods but Add Order summary and payment summary on paypal adaptive payment not working

```
function Pay()
{
    $PayRequestFields = array(
                            'ActionType' => 'PAY',                              // Required.  Whether the request pays the receiver or whether the request is set up to create a payment request, but not fulfill the payment until the ExecutePayment is called.  Values are:  PAY, CREATE, PAY_PRIMARY
                            'CancelURL' => site_url('paypal/adaptive_payments/pay_cancel'),                                     // Required.  The URL to which the sender's browser is redirected if the sender cancels the approval for the payment after logging in to paypal.com.  1024 char max.
                            'CurrencyCode' => 'AUD',                                // Required.  3 character currency code.
                            'FeesPayer' => 'EACHRECEIVER',                                  // The payer of the fees.  Values are:  SENDER, PRIMARYRECEIVER, EACHRECEIVER, SECONDARYONLY
                            'IPNNotificationURL' => '',                         // The URL to which you want all IPN messages for this payment to be sent.  1024 char max.
                            'Memo' => '',                                       // A note associated with the payment (text, not HTML).  1000 char max
                            'Pin' => '',                                        // The sener's personal id number, which was specified when the sender signed up for the preapproval
                            'PreapprovalKey' => '',                             // The key associated with a preapproval for this payment.  The preapproval is required if this is a preapproved payment.  
                            'ReturnURL' => site_url('paypal/adaptive_payments/pay_return'),                                     // Required.  The URL to which the sener's browser is redirected after approvaing a payment on paypal.com.  1024 char max.
                            'ReverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError' => '',          // Whether to reverse paralel payments if an error occurs with a payment.  Values are:  TRUE, FALSE
                            'SenderEmail' => '',                                // Sender's email address.  127 char max.
                            'TrackingID' => ''                                  // Unique ID that you specify to track the payment.  127 char max.
                            );

    $ClientDetailsFields = array(
                            'CustomerID' => '',                                 // Your ID for the sender  127 char max.
                            'CustomerType' => '',                               // Your ID of the type of customer.  127 char max.
                            'GeoLocation' => '',                                // Sender's geographic location
                            'Model' => '',                                      // A sub-identification of the application.  127 char max.
                            'PartnerName' => ''                                 // Your organization's name or ID
                            );

    $FundingTypes = array('ECHECK', 'BALANCE', 'CREDITCARD');

    $Receivers = array();
    $Receiver = array(
                    'Amount' => '25'
                    'Email' => 'a@b.com', 
                    // Receiver's email address. 127 char max.
                    'InvoiceID' => '',                                          // The invoice number for the payment.  127 char max.
                    'PaymentType' => '',                                        // Transaction type.  Values are:  GOODS, SERVICE, PERSONAL, CASHADVANCE, DIGITALGOODS
                    'PaymentSubType' => '',                                     // The transaction subtype for the payment.
                    'Phone' => array('CountryCode' => '', 'PhoneNumber' => '', 'Extension' => ''), // Receiver's phone number.   Numbers only.
                    'Primary' => ''                                             // Whether this receiver is the primary receiver.  Values are:  TRUE, FALSE
                    );
    array_push($Receivers,$Receiver);

    $Receiver = array(
                    'Amount' => '10',       
                    'Description' => 'asdfghj', 
                    // Required.  Amount to be paid to the receiver.
                    'Email' => 'b@c.com', 
                    // Receiver's email address. 127 char max.
                    'InvoiceID' => '',                                          // The invoice number for the payment.  127 char max.
                    'PaymentType' => '',                                        // Transaction type.  Values are:  GOODS, SERVICE, PERSONAL, CASHADVANCE, DIGITALGOODS
                    'PaymentSubType' => '',                                     // The transaction subtype for the payment.
                    'Phone' => array('CountryCode' => '', 'PhoneNumber' => '', 'Extension' => ''), // Receiver's phone number.   Numbers only.
                    'Primary' => ''                                             // Whether this receiver is the primary receiver.  Values are:  TRUE, FALSE
                    );
    array_push($Receivers,$Receiver);
    //print_r($Receivers);die;



    $SenderIdentifierFields = array(
                                    'UseCredentials' => ''                      // If TRUE, use credentials to identify the sender.  Default is false.
                                    );

    $AccountIdentifierFields = array(
                                    'Email' => '',                              // Sender's email address.  127 char max.
                                    'Phone' => array('CountryCode' => '', 'PhoneNumber' => '', 'Extension' => '')                               // Sender's phone number.  Numbers only.
                                    );

    $PayPalRequestData = array(
                        'PayRequestFields' => $PayRequestFields, 
                        'ClientDetailsFields' => $ClientDetailsFields, 
                        'FundingTypes' => $FundingTypes, 
                        'Receivers' => $Receivers, 
                        'SenderIdentifierFields' => $SenderIdentifierFields, 
                        'AccountIdentifierFields' => $AccountIdentifierFields
                        );  

    $PayPalResult = $this->paypal_adaptive->Pay($PayPalRequestData);

    if(!$this->paypal_adaptive->APICallSuccessful($PayPalResult['Ack']))
    {
        $errors = array('Errors'=>$PayPalResult['Errors']);
        $this->load->view('front/error',$errors);
    }
    else
    {
        // Successful call.  Load view or whatever you need to do here. 
        echo '<pre />';
        print_r($PayPalResult);
        echo '<p><a href="' . $PayPalResult['RedirectURL'] . '">PROCEED TO PAYPAL</a></p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: not working how?  error message?  Just not doing what you expected?  Please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Express checkout is not use the adaptive payment library.

You can use the express checkout API and provide a paypal seller account id (email) different from the one making the API call. This configuration allow parallel payment in express checkout (even in redirect mode) and you can controll to which user part of the total amount of the order go.

And with express checkout, controlling the cart detail is very easy.

A link to the documentation : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/

Comment: I have to split payment(Adaptive) of multiple paypal account, and show order history on user paypal checkout

Comment: Yes, it is what you have to implement using Parallel Payment, you can split your amount first and then use parallel transition and you will get what you want